# Help on multiple meta_query

Tags: meta-query

I am trying to fetch from the WP database posts with two meta_key values, but the result is `0` posts.

Print out of the arguments:

```
Array ( 
    [taxonomy] => cardstax 
    [term] => christmas 
    [post_type] => cards 
    [paged] => 1 
    [caller_get_posts] => 1 
    [meta_query] => Array ( 
        [relation] => AND 
        [0] => Array (
            [key] => card_format[value] => Little card 
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
            [key] => price_lvl 
            [value] => Array ( 
                [0] => 0.06 
                [1] => 0.97 
                ) 
            [type] => NUMERIC 
            [compare] => BETWEEN 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

The Meta query itself

```
'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
'term' => $term->slug,
'post_type' => 'cards',
'paged'=> $paged,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1,    
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'card_format',
        'value'   => 'Little card'
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'price_lvl',
        'value'   => array( "0.06","0.97" ),
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    ),
```

The SQL syntax:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS plt_posts.ID
FROM plt_posts
INNER JOIN plt_term_relationships ON ( plt_posts.ID = plt_term_relationships.object_id ) 
INNER JOIN plt_postmeta ON ( plt_posts.ID = plt_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN plt_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( plt_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
JOIN plt_icl_translations t ON plt_posts.ID = t.element_id
    AND t.element_type =  'post_cards'
JOIN plt_icl_languages l ON t.language_code = l.code
    AND l.active =1
WHERE 1 =1
    AND ( plt_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 27 ) )
    AND plt_posts.post_type =  'cards'
    AND (
        plt_posts.post_status =  'publish'
        OR plt_posts.post_status =  'private'
    )
    AND (
        (
        plt_postmeta.meta_key =  'card_format'
        AND CAST( plt_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR ) =  'Little card'
    )
    AND (
        mt1.meta_key =  'price_lvl'
        AND CAST( mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED ) 
            BETWEEN  '0.06'
            AND  '0.97'
        )
    )
    AND t.language_code =  'lv'
GROUP BY plt_posts.ID
ORDER BY plt_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 12
```

Without that part

```
AND (
    mt1.meta_key =  'price_lvl'
    AND CAST( mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED ) 
        BETWEEN  '0.06'
        AND  '0.97'
    )
```

The query works fine and I get a list of post IDs.

Comment: Is it really ***that hard*** to format code in a readable way when seeking for help?

Comment: KHm, I think I did.

Comment: [Nope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/119565/revisions), you didn't.

Comment: Does changing the TYPE to DECIMAL help in 2nd Meta Query, because numeric will consider both of them as 0, I guess?

Comment: Do you get the right results when execution with online one f the meta queries?

Comment: dot1: Nope, nothing changes. 0 posts.

Comment: Roel, please explain a abit more. Without the mt1.meta_key =  'price_lvl' part, result is what it should be.

Comment: Khm, I thing I found it. Changed DECIMAL and NUMERIC to CHAR and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the values for your second meta query. You're comparing numbers to chars, which won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Changed DECIMAL and NUMERIC to CHAR and it worked out.